# Private nuget source github returns 401 with correct credentials

Tags: .net, github, nuget, rider

I have a nuget package that is hosted on my private repository.
I added the minimum amount of scope flags at first but later added a lot more, except for a few admin level ones.

Now when adding the source to my global 'nuget.config' in the IDE (Rider/jetbrains) It prompts me for my github credentials but after entering and confirming those it almost straight away asks again. I am also not able to see the packages in the nuget panel.

I tried going to the api and it accepted the same credentials I entered in the IDE

```
https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myusername/index.json
```

Setting the source in the IDE nuget panel also added it to the global 'nuget.config'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myusername/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This is all done from the same desktop where I am logged in under a single gh account on IDE and ssh.

When adding a private source I don't need the token used for pushing the package right?
The repo is set to private if that matters at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsure what exactly caused it but I removed all global and sln level sources.

```
dotnet nuget list source
..........
..sources.
..........
dotnet nuget remove source <source name>
```

Then only using dotnet cli nuget tool I added a global source.
These are set globally for a repo here. When using this source, flags from dotnet cli will override any of these if set.

```
dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/GITHUB_USERNAME/index.json --name "Github" --username "GITHUB_USERNAME" --password <PAT TOKEN FROM GITHUB> --store-password-in-clear-text --valid-authentication-types basic
```

Set auth type to basic for pat see [options properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source)
The PAT token has the scopes for packages:

- read
- write
- delete

Some misc scopes:

- notifications
- workflow

After this I did not test it yet but made a new package using the new source and pushed it using dotnet CLI

```
dotnet build
dotnet pack ./library.sln 
dotnet nuget push ./bin/Debug/NetNugetDemo.1.0.4.nupkg --api-key <SAME PAT TOKEN GITHUB> --source "Github"
```

The extra arg for adding the PAT token again might not be necessary but I just wanted to be sure.

Made a new cli project, the github source was available no issues and packages as well.

Comment: One minor thing is that that remove command should be `dotnet nuget remove source <source_name>`.

Comment: Same, lost access for an unknown reason. These commands reinstated my access. Would be good to understand why access might have been lost.

Comment: This was happening to me when I `dotnet restore` in my new laptop. The old one worked fine. Was driving me nuts trying to figure out the cause. But the above steps saved my life.